# How to get "Queries used to find your business" from GMB PHP API

Tags: php, api, google-my-business-api

thanks for reading!

I'm semi-proficient with the PHP Google my business library for reporting but I can't find any documentation on retrieving the "Queries used to find your business" data which is displayed in the GMB dashboard (screenshot below),

Is there a way to retrieve this data?

[image]

Comment: The metrics you're looking for are not currently available. I wish they were. Check [this page](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/Metric) which shows which metrics are available, as well as the [location insights endpoint](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/insight-data)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in @limeygent 's comment, this data is not available through the API, available fields are here: https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/Metric

Damn.